# How can I update the title in my matplotlib Animation?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, title

I'm trying to set the title as 'Electric Field of mode (i)', where i goes from 1 to N, but I don't find the way. After I import Numpy, Matplotlib, cmath and Animation, and define the parameters and neccesary funtions (modo) I have:

```
fig = plt.figure()
subplot = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 60*(10**(-15))), xlabel=("t[s]"), ylim=(-10, 10), ylabel=("Amplitud [u.a.]"))
modo, = subplot.plot([], [], lw=2)
    def init1():
     modo.set_data([],[])
     return modo,

def animacion1(i):
     EiR, Ei = Modo(Eo, wo, dw, t, phio, i)
     modo.set_data(t,EiR)
     return modo,

anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animacion1, init_func=init1, frames=N, interval=20, blit=True, save_count=20000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


x = np.linspace(0, 7.5, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line1, = ax.plot(x, y1, color='orange')

def update(num):
    line1.set_data(x[:num], y1[:num])
    ax.set_title(f'{num}')
    return line1

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=update, frames=len(x),
                              interval = 50)

plt.show()
```

In your case you need to do `subplot.set_title(f'Electric Field of mode ({i})')` in your `animacion1()` method.